# How to refer file located in current application into file in SD card

Tags: blackberry

I have a one script file in my current application.. The path for same look like this.

```
 D:\myproj\Example\www\abc.js
```

while running my application in device it will download one file into my SDcard dynamically.

I need to parse my downloaded application and need to set this "abc.js" file path in this.

I can able to set path if my file is in SDCard , but dont know how to refer path which is in my current application..

Answer (score 2):

If you have that file on SDCard, then the full path to it will be as follows:

```
file:///SDCard/myproj/Example/www/abc.js
```

ADDITIONAL INFO:

If your file is located in cod file, then there is a way, but it is not documented and it is not guaranteed that it will work on all devices and RIM OS versions.

Code below shows `document.htm` encapsulated in `modulename.cod` in BlackBerry browser.

```
BrowserSession session = Browser.getDefaultSession();
session.displayPage("cod://modulename/document.htm" );
```

Try to use `cod://modulename/abc.js` to specify path to your js file.

Comment: Thanks for help.. but my file is in my application not SD card.

Comment: I added new info to my post. Please check it.

Answer (score 0):

To reference an application embedded file (in this case an image file stored in *images* directory):

```
    "file:///local/images/embedded_img.png"
```